# The specified Gradle installation directory does not appear to contain a Gradle distribution

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I use Eclipse for JavaEE developer, version 4.5.1 (Mars.1) with Gradle plug-in, Gradle buildship plugin. This is my settings:
[image]

I create new Spring starter project (Spring Boot), then I face this error:
[image]

Error message:

> The specified Gradle installation directory does not appear to contain
>   a Gradle distribution

Please help me resolve this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

in gradle wrapper change distribution url the latest one ...it will be  solved

Comment: where I can find gradlew instillation, on window ?

Comment: got it thanks, this worked fro me, 

Run gradle wrapper task   --- gradle wrapper

Run command mentioned by @Ucdemir

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late, but I a very had a similar issue -
Essentially for me, when I updated the gradle path in the UI I did not see the change reflected in .settings/org.eclipse.buildship.core.prefs

When I updated the the Gradle path in Eclipse to the correct one I would get the old path in the error message.

To resolve the issue, I had to change the gradle build distribution path in org.eclipse.buildship.core.prefs in the .settings folder through windows.

Updated the incorrect path (to the gradle-3.4.1 folder) and the issue seemed to be resolved.